# How to find an unknown state in a Markov Decision Process?

Tags: markov-process

I'm trying to find or develop an algorithm that will identify a missing state in a Markov Decision Process.

For example, if we initialize the chain with state:

$$0  \to 0 \to 0 \to 0$$

but the system can be better modeled by:

$$0 \to  X \to 0 \to 0 \to 0 $$

where $X$ is an additional state not created or known by the model builder - Is there an algorithm that will find $X$?

If not - what would be required to create such an algorithm?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "initialize the chain"?  By definition, the evolution of a Markov chain is independent of all preceding states, so your indication of four or five states and transitions among them seems irrelevant.

Comment: I am specifically referring to a Markov decision process of an unknown order; it may be a simple decision process, or it may be a 3, 4, or Nth order process.

Comment: Thank you--I had guessed it might be something like that.  It's still unclear what you're asking about, though.